# Grouping and concatenating columns with multiple results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need help performing this grouping, I wish to concatenate the columns with multiple results and sum columns numeric values

[image]

I have tried this code the outcome is to shown on the left point arrow, but I am hoping to achieve the outcome at the bottom pointing arrow.

```
winback.astype(str).groupby('day').agg(',' .join).reset_index()
```

Thank you for your assistamce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `agg` with dictionary

```
winback.groupby('day').agg({'smoker': ','.join, 'sum': 'sum'})
```